# How to handle audio focus when other apps do not respect focus loss policy

Tags: android

My navigation app have to play direction hints as ordinary navigation apps do. Before playing message I used audio focus policy as described here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/08/respecting-audio-focus.html

Unfortunately this does not work in all the cases, obviously problematic apps does not meet audio focus policy, still this explanation is not satisfying for my users so I wonder if there is a way to solve this problem ?

What I tried is switching audio streams while setting MUSIC stream to mute, however my app also handles volume changes internally, so during switch I need to get volume level from one stream set it to another then revert changes after playback and finally unmute previous stream. To sum up this looks awful and still has some drawbacks which can influence user experience.

Anyone solved this ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Unless I'm doing something wrong, surprisingly YouTube does not release audio focus when it stops playing. I'm yet to find a solution